# boost asio custom allocator handler io service post compile errors

Tags: c++, templates, boost, bind, boost-asio

I have working io_service post call that looks as follows:

```
  _io_service.post(std::tr1::bind(&BlitzLogger::push,this,
                                    std::tr1::bind(&BlitzLogger::stringer<typename boost::decay<T const &>::type,
                                                   typename boost::decay<Args const &>::type ...>, this,
                                                   t, args ...)));
```

I suspect the bind calls are having some overhead that can be done away with, so I proceeded to lay out the custom allocators for handlers as described at

```
 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/allocation/server.cpp
```

Following this, I would like to do something as follows:

```
_io_service.post(
    makeCustomAllocHandler(_allocator1,std::tr1::bind(&BlitzLogger::push,this,
    makeCustomAllocHandler(_allocator2,std::tr1::bind(&BlitzLogger::stringer<typename boost::decay<T const &>::type,
                                                      typename boost::decay<Args const &>::type ...>,this,t,args ...)))));
```

This piece of code above throws compile time errors **(host of template argument deduction / substitution failures)**, 
however, if I remove the _io_service.post call, and limit it to

```
    makeCustomAllocHandler(_allocator1,std::tr1::bind(&BlitzLogger::push,this,
    makeCustomAllocHandler(_allocator2,std::tr1::bind(&BlitzLogger::stringer<typename boost::decay<T const &>::type,
                                                      typename boost::decay<Args const &>::type ...>,this,t,args ...))));
```

then the code compiles fine.

So obviously the problem is that the return type of makeCustomAllocHandler is not compliant with the template handler argument of the post function.

Why is this happening, and how do I get around this problem.

Comment: Consider using a profiler to identify bottlenecks.  Custom allocator handlers will not remove the overhead of invoking `std::bind()` or the functors it returns, as the [`asio_handler_allocate()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_allocate.html) hooks are only used to control the allocation strategy for temporary handlers.  To minimize functor call overhead, one would need to write specific functors rather than wrapping `std::bind` functors.

Comment: @TannerSansbury yes, the perf numbers seem to suggest what you're saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be compatible with [CompletionHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/CompletionHandler.html) object returned by `makeCustomAllocHandler` should define `void operator()()` instead of `void operator()(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)` required by [ReadHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) and used in server example.

Comment: already doing that like so 
void operator()(){
        _handler();
      }

Comment: your example does not contain any methods definitions and error details, so it is hard to guess what can be wrong. you can at least declare `std::function<void()>` object and try to replace your `bind` and `makeCustomAllocHandler` one by one with references to that object to see when error disappears.

Comment: e.g. if you have `std::function<void()> f` then `_io_service.post(f)` should compile, then `_io_service.post(makeCustomAllocHandler(_allocator1, f))` should compile as well and so on.

Comment: hmm you're right, the inner handler actually returns a string, so i'll need a std::string operator()() for that. Thanks